# Star rating css broken on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

With HTML, CSS and some jQuery I display star rating on my webshop.

This works great, just like the JSFiddle, on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.
But it is broken on Internet Explorer 9 and 10, and I do not know how to fix this problem.

See how it is displayed on IE:

[image]

How can I fix this.

Input line:

```
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio"/>
    <label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tqf54vLc/

Comment: jsFiddle works for me in IE 9, 10, 11!

Comment: I can't see the image at the moment as I'm in school so I'm not sure if this helps (hence comment instead of answer), but have you tried setting different properties? For example, using `border` instead of `color` seems to work for me. This does mess up your styling though.  (Seeing @PraveenKumar 's comment: it does not work for me)

Comment: @jaunt The jsFiddle doesn't have fontawesome included. Please include and check!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah I knew I missed something! You're absolutely right. **No repo.**